# How to find which page orientation user selects in Rave (Delphi 7)

Tags: delphi, orientation, rave-reports

Is there a way to find which page orientation (poLandscape or poPortrait) user selects furing preview setup? I have tried this code:

```
if RvSystem1.SystemPrinter.Orientation=poPortrait then 
ShowMessage('Portrait')
else 
ShowMessage('Landscape');
```

But this code give "Portrait" even if I select Landscape from setup. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is really old, but Rave Reports is no longer. I suggest anyone who reads this to STRONGLY consider using another reporting engine e.g.

Fast Report - http://www.fast-report.com/

Comment: This answer really looks like spam (and I do like fast-report)

Comment: I am in no way affiliated with them. People need to be aware if they come to read this.